# Attribute android:letterSpacing not working in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am using BottomNavigationView and trying to set the android:letterSpacing attribute on texts by defining it on styles.xml, but whatever value I put, it does not make any difference, but if I use it on textview or something like that, it works perfectly!

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/ripple"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_item_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_item_color"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/multicontent_container"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:elevation="8dp"/>

<style name="Widget.BottomNavigationView" parent="Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/bottom_navigation_font</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">4sp</item>
        <item name="android:letterSpacing">-1</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe you can try with this :

```
<item name="android:letterSpacing">0.1</item>
```

I don't know about the scale, but it works for me, you can play with different values and see what is more convenient for you, but unfortunately I don't know the equivalence of "-1". My two cents, hope it can help.